# Exercise on Little "o"

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

I am working on asymptotic behavior of a function and this is the question i came ;

$$f(x)=\lim _{x\to 0^-}\left({e^{\frac{x^2-1}{x}}}\right)$$

it can be solve with simple limit chain rule but how it can be solve with the help of **Little (o) notation**.

Comment: You can solve that with $\textbf o$ notation. However, knowing that the limit is equal to $\infty$, is it really useful? You need to write $g = \textbf o(f)$. with $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^-}  g(x) = \infty$.

Comment: how i can find g(x),sir pardon me i am new in asymptotic behavior

Comment: You can try to prove that $-1/x =\textbf{o}(f(x))$ as $x \to 0^-$.

Comment: thanks sir i got it

Comment: sir what if limit goes to  x→0+ side g(x) will go to ∞ .but actually f(x) will go to 0. how i can use little o notation for that